# Passing viewmodel to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi guys I am trying to pass data through a view model to a partial view for it to generate a graph.

I tried the following in my main view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report";
}
@model WebApplication1.ViewModel.DatapointLineViewModel
```

I am passing the ViewModel to the partial view in this manner:

```
 @{
  Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_report_bar.cshtml",WebApplication1.ViewModel.DatapointLineViewModel); }
```

I am trying to use the data in the ViewModel through Viewbags:

> `labels: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints),`

I am getting the following error:

> CS0119: 'DatapointLineViewModel' is a type, which is not valid in the
>   given context

This is my View Model:

```
 [DataContract]
    public class DatapointLineViewModel
    {

        public DatapointLineViewModel(string label, double y)
        {
            this.Label = label;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
        [DataMember(Name = "label")]
        public string Label = "";

        //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
        [DataMember(Name = "y")]
        public Nullable<double> Y = null;
    }
```

The controller:

```
 public ActionResult BarChart()
        {
            List<DatapointLineViewModel> dataPoints = new List<DatapointLineViewModel>();

            dataPoints.Add(new DatapointLineViewModel("USA", 71));
            dataPoints.Add(new DatapointLineViewModel("Great Britain", 67));
            dataPoints.Add(new DatapointLineViewModel("China", 70));
            dataPoints.Add(new DatapointLineViewModel("Russia", 56));
            dataPoints.Add(new DatapointLineViewModel("Germany", 42));
            dataPoints.Add(new DatapointLineViewModel("Japan", 41));
            //dataPoints.Add(new DatapointLineViewModel("France", 42));
            //dataPoints.Add(new DatapointLineViewModel("South Korea", 21));

            ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);

            return View();
        }
```

Script in partial view:

```
 data: {
                labels: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints),
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'My First dataset',
                        data: WebApplication1.ViewModel.DatapointLineViewModel,
                        options: {
                            legend: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        },
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(152,235,239,0.8)',
                            'rgba(152,235,239,0.8)',
                            'rgba(152,235,239,0.8)',
                            'rgba(152,235,239,0.8)',
                            'rgba(152,235,239,0.8)',
                            'rgba(152,235,239,0.8)'],

                    },
```

Why is it so? Need Help:).

Comment: If the model in both the main view and partial view is `DatapointLineViewModel`, then its just `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_report_bar"); }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi I tried the same but the data is not being reflected in the partial view, hence tried this. Where have I gone wrong? :)

Comment: Why are you using `ViewBag` - you have already passed the model to the partial. And you have not even shown where and how you add the data to `ViewBag` (and what is `DataPoints`? is that a property of `DatapointLineViewModel`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi, new to this and trying it out, I believe I have misunderstood a certain concept , hence I have attached the model and controller. I am attempting to pass data from the controller to the script present in the partial view through the main view. Could you point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Delete you `ViewBag.DataPoints` and use `return View(dataPoints);`. Then to serialize that to a javascript array, use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi did the same , but the data being passed was null, then I changed the model type to  IEnumerable and it is being passed. Thanks a ton:) I feel I have misunderstood the concept of ViewModel and viewbags, could you help me with it:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178851/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-abhilash-gopalakrishna).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember you're wanting to pass actual data at this point, not a type.

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_report_bar.cshtml", Model);
}
```

`Model` contains the instance of the data itself, and this is what you're wanting to pass to the partial.

Comment: The 2nd parameter is not really necessary in this case (the model in the main view is passed by default)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Really? I didn't know that! Going to try that now, thanks!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well I'll be. That works too. I'll leave the answer as is in this case, as I think it's instructive to illustrate the difference between the actual data and the type, but thanks for that.

Comment: @JohnH Hi tried the same but the ViewBag is empty. The data is not being passed in the view bag. I will attach the screenshot in the question for reference.

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna What are you needing to use `ViewBag` for if you've already got a view model?

Comment: @JohnH Hi, new to this and trying it out, I believe I have misunderstood a certain concept , hence I have attached the model and controller. I am attempting to pass data from the controller to the script present in the partial view through the main view. Could you point me in the right direction :)